# How to make a cx_oracle connection encrypted using ssl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, ssl, cx-oracle

I am using cx_oracle module with python 3.7 version and I need to check whether the connection is encrypted. If not I need to set the ssl as true in order to make it encrypted.

Here is my piece of code to make the connection:

```
import cx_Oracle
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host='127.0.0.1', port=1521, sid='your_sid')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='your_username', password='your_password', dsn=dsn)
conn.close()
```

Comment: For reference, if you don't want to set up SSL/TLS itself, you can very quickly use Oracle's native network encryption, see the cx_Oracle doc [Securely Encrypting Network Traffic to Oracle Database](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#securely-encrypting-network-traffic-to-oracle-database).

Answer (score 6):

As you are thinking in enabling security to your connection, your first step should be to use a `wallet`, even before considering using `ssl` , and avoid using passwords. It does not matter how encrypted is your network traffic, if your passwords are visible in your Python programs. I know it is not part of the question itself, but it is a very good practice and available for `cx_Oracle`.

One example ( *My Python programs runs in a Linux client machine which connects to an Oracle Database in Linux too using `ssl`* )

**Client Side**

1.Create the wallet

```
mkstore -wrl "/home/myuser/wallet_directory" -create
```

2.Create the credential

```
mkstore -wrl "/home/myuser/wallet_directory" -createCredential mynetalias myuser myuserpw
```

Where `mynetalias` is an alias for my `tns` string connection which I will store on my `tnsnames.ora` file. In my example I will use the same directory where I created the wallet.

3.Create the `tnsnames.ora` and add the same alias used in the wallet

```
mynetalias =
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dbhost.example.com)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVER = DEDICATED)
            (SERVICE_NAME = orclpdb1)
        )
    )
```

4.Create the `sqlnet.ora` file

```
WALLET_LOCATION =
    (SOURCE =
        (METHOD = FILE)
        (METHOD_DATA =
            (DIRECTORY = /home/myuser/wallet_dir)
        )
    )
SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
```

5.Add your `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable to your bash profile.

```
cd
echo "export TNS_ADMIN=/home/myuser/wallet_directory" >> .bashrc
```

If you definitely know that the database server enforces integrity and encryption, then you do not need to configure anything in the client side. However you can also, or alternatively, do so depending on your business needs. Add the following lines to the `sqlnet.ora` file where the wallet is located

```
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_CLIENT = required
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_CLIENT = (SHA512)
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT = required
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT = (AES256)
```

**Database Side**

In order to setup `SSL` and `encryption` we need to add these values to the Database `sqlnet.ora` file. Review your requirements and discuss the right security algorithms. In my case my database accepts connection either way ( with or without  encryption ).

```
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_SERVER = accepted
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_SERVER = (SHA512)
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER = accepted
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER = (AES256)
```

You might want to review these parameters here:

[SQLNET Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netrf/parameters-for-the-sqlnet.ora.html#GUID-8D134504-AFBA-489F-A663-E747A4660D46)

**How to connect**

Normal

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(dsn="mynetalias")
```

Pool

```
pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(externalauth=True, homogeneous=False,
                             dsn="mynetalias")
pool.acquire()
```

Remember that `dsn` must match exactly the alias used in your `tnsnames.ora` configured before.

Use the information provided by the view `V$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO` to assure your connection is encrypted ( field `network_service_banner`)

Comment: Nice mentioning of the wallet to remove the readable credentials from configs.

Comment: @ik_zelf, thank you for your kind comment. Indeed I think it was worth mentioning, as I believe it won't matter too much that you have ssl when anyone can read your passwords ;)

Comment: I removed my answer.

Comment: Setting TNS_ADMIN in a .bashrc file is OK for some use cases (and operating systems or shells), but not all. For other choices see cx_Oracle doc on [Optional Oracle Net Configuration Files](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#optional-oracle-net-configuration-files) (e.g. tnsnames.ora).

Comment: I'm no security expert but this answer appears to set up Oracle's "native network encryption", which is certainly better than nothing.  Setting up SSL is covered in the Oracle doc https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-secure-sockets-layer-authentication.html#GUID-85027CCD-62A0-4E95-8B02-020745D50900

Answer (score 0):

we can use python-oracledb driver which is the major version successor to cx_Oracle 8.3. https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/introduction.html

reference to the code: https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/discussions/34

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32441194)